# php mysql удаляет символ \ при вставке

Tags: php, mysql

```
update shop_items_rows_values set value = '5\3' where id_row = '94' and id_item = '1'
```

В базе оказывается значение `53`.

Comment: Экранировать надо. Судя по всему у вас код может быть подвержен sql-инъекциям.

Answer (score 4):

Символ "\" является специальным для SQL, и его надо экранировать.

Если он прописан в запросе явно, руками, то его надо удвоить:

```
update shop_items_rows_values set value = '5\\3' where id_row = '94' and id_item = '1'
```

Если же значение подставляется в запрос динамически, то такое значение надо передавать через **плейсхолдер:**

```
$sql = "update shop_items_rows_values set value = ? where id_row = ? and id_item = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(['5\\3', 94, 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Символ слеша служит для экранирования данных, т.е. применение слеша к символу часто меняет его значение. Например \n означает символ перевода строки, \t - символ табуляции. В случае чисел больше 0, слеш оставляет символ числа без изменения. Однако, сам он не сохраняется. Если вы хотите сохранить слеш, вам следует преобразовать строку в '5\\3'. И это без учета внешних строк, так как эта строка может быть сама быть частью другой строки.